# QLPreviewController and the new swipe down to dismiss Multi-tasking gesture in iOS 9

Tags: ios9, gesture, multitasking, qlpreviewcontroller

I use QLPreviewController to view images in my application.  I'm supporting iOS 9 at the moment but still building with Xcode 6.4 (would love to upgrade but it's up to corporate when we go to the new Xcode). We use storyboards auto layout etc.

I noticed in the latest test flight build on my personal iPhone 6S (iOS 9.1) while viewing an image in QLPreviewController I can use a swipe down gesture to dismiss the controller.  But after that I get a blank screen in my application.

I do hit the previewControllerDidDismiss: delegate method, but I have not been able to once again make the presenting controller's view visible.  I have tried

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bringSubviewToFront: self.view];
```

Any help or advice you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with your app's code? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  Just submitted (23905821) and included a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the bug report engineering let me know that this issue was caused by the modal presentation mode I was using for my QLPreviewController.

I switched from UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen to UIModalPresentationFullScreen and that gave me the behavior I expected.

Now when I swipe down to dismiss the QLPreviewController I see the view that presented it. (No additional code was required so I got rid of the previewControllerDidDismiss: delegate method).